# Is it possible to transfer data to NFC tag without Beam? Any alternatives?

Tags: android, tags, share, nfc, android-beam

We have an Android app that writes data to a NFC tag using Android Beam. After deprecation of Beam in sdk 29, is there any alternative for data transference with a NFC tag?
Is it possible to use Google Nearby Share with a NFC tag?
I didn't found any documentation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Nearby Share is Bluetooth or Wifi Direct as these were deemed by method to transfer data in the deprecation of Android Beam.

It should be technically possible to still transfer data via NFC without Android Beam, though there are some technical difficulties to over come.

One Device pretends to be a NFC Card with Host Card Emulation (HCE) and the other device reads/writes to it as if it was a normal Type 4 NFC card.

There are some complications if one device still has Android Beam but using the `enableReaderMode` NFC API to read/write to the Emulated Card should get around this.

I think some people of StackOverflow have tried this, I have not personally but the process of using HCE should be technically possible.